# Detect the difference between two arrays using laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

I have two arrays and I need to verify what is different between them, like:
Something exists in array A but not in B,
One argument is diferent in array A when comparing to B...

```
$temp = import_temp::select('cod_disciplina', 'cod_turma', 'hr_inicio', 'hr_fim', 'dia_semana')->get();
        $turmas;
        foreach($temp as $t)
        {
           $turmas = Horario::select('cod_disciplina', 'cod_turma', 'hr_inicio', 'hr_fim', 'dia_semana')
            ->whereIn('cod_disciplina', $temp->lists('cod_disciplina'))
            ->whereIn('cod_turma', $temp->lists('cod_turma'))
            ->where('ano_semestre', $ano_semestre)->get();
        }
```

When I do:

```
 print_r($turmas->toArray()); 
 print_r($temp->toArray());
```

I get:
[image]

How may I compare these keys and identify when something `changed` is `new` or is `missing`.

Tried working with `array_diff_assoc` but I get the following error:

> Array to string conversion

```
array_diff_assoc($temp->toArray(),   $turmas->toArray());
```

Also tried [This that I found in another answer in a similar question](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php#73972) but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First define your own function to compare arrays:

```
function arrayCmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a < $b) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($a > $b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then if you want elements that are present in `$a` bot not in `$b` then you call:

```
$diff = array_udiff($a, $b, 'arrayCmp');
```

Comment: What if I have all the elements inside both but one or more of this elements have diferente value(s) ?

Comment: What you said is contradiction. If some elements have different values then they are different elements and cannot be inside both.